# There is no software install app

Tags: software-installation, deb

I tried to install a .deb file but I can’t it says I open it with archive manager for some reason

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. *deb* packages are built for a specific release; we currently don't know your thus can't provide specific help (ie. your question should start with clues as to what Ubuntu product & release you're using; not all Ubuntu products use *deb* files).

Comment: There is a package installation tool on the command line `dpkg -i package.deb` but that alone probably won't solve your problem as it sounds like you have some incompatibilites and/or dependency issues. Might be worth doing a bit of reading on package management: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management?ref=getbetterdevops

Answer (score 0):

Don't download random .deb packages if you are a novice. It's too easy to break your system that way.

Use the proper applications to download and install software safely and easily:

- Ubuntu Software (Desktop)
- Apt (Desktop and Server)

If your software is not available there, then ask here about how to install it. Provide a link to the software's web page.

The phrasing of the question suggests that you double-clicked on a trusted .deb (trust is important), which should normally open Ubuntu Software and offer to install. So make sure your have the `snap-store` snap installed.

`sudo snap install snap-store`.